# How do I make relations laravel in different folders?

Tags: laravel, models, laravel-5.6, relation

My user model like this :

```
namespace App\Models\Auth;
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class, 'vendor_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

My vendor model like this :

```
namespace App\Models;
...
class Vendor extends Model
{
    ...
    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id', 'vendor_id');
    }
}
```

If the relation run, there exist error like this :

```
Class 'App\Models\Auth\Vendor' not found
```

It seems that the error occurred because the vendor model is not in the auth folder

How do I solve that error without moving the vendor model to the auth folder?

Comment: Take your time to through http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple word, you **need to import Vendor class into the User class.**

```
namespace App\Models\Auth;
use App\Models\Vendor; //code to be added
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class, 'vendor_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it's because you didn't explicitly load the Vendor class into the User file.

Add into your User file

```
use App\Models\Vendor;
```